# BigBlueButton and Greenlight - Invalid BigBlueButton Endpoint and Secret when configuring TURN server

Tags: bigbluebutton

I had BBB with Greenlight working well.

After configuring the TURN server using the following docs: https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/setup-turn-server.html#setup-a-turn-server

I get the following error in Greenlight: `Invalid BigBlueButton Endpoint and Secret`

**Note: My BBB secret is valid and is the same for Greenlight .env file.**

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason may be problem with container DNS

Run bash inside the container with "docker exec -it greenlight-v2 bash" and inside the container try ping google.com. If it return error then open dns file with "vi /etc/resolv.conf" and add extra line for 4.2.2.4 or any dns you like/

Answer (score 0):

Same problem (the suggested DNS check passes OK).

Uncommenting turn server in turn-stun-servers.xml :

```
<bean id="turn1" class="org.bigbluebutton.web.services.turn.TurnServer">
        Secret:
        <constructor-arg index="0" value=" ... same as in turnserevr "/>
        TURN server URL, use turn: or turns:
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="turn:turn.my.domain:443?transport=tcp"/>
        TTL in seconds for shared secret
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="86400"/>
    </bean>

<property name="turnServers">
            <set>
                <ref bean="turn1" />
```

leads to "Invalid BigBlueButton Endpoint and Secret".
Restarting bbb gives:

```
# Potential problems described below
# Not running:  tomcat7 or grails LibreOffice
................................................................................
# Error: Could not connect to the configured hostname/IP address
#
#    https://bbb.my.domain/
```

Also, turnserver launched under turnserver user can't bind

```
0: Trying to bind fd 16 to <127.0.0.1:443>: errno=13
0: Cannot bind TLS/TCP listener socket to addr 127.0.0.1:443
0: Fatal final failure: cannot bind TLS/TCP listener socket to addr 127.0.0.1:443
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if bbb-conf --secret yield the same endpoint and secret key as in your .env file. If everything looks good then do the following to force renewal of certificate.

1. apt-get install snapd
2. apt-get remove -y certbot
3. snap install certbot --classic
4. certbot renew --force-renewal --preferred-chain "ISRG Root X1"
5. bbb-conf --clean
6. sudo systemctl restart ngnix